# Target text in element without targeting the child element strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to target the word "Apple" in the html below with the script below, but it will target all the strings inside the parent container. How do I target the text that isn't wrapped? One solution would be to wrap the text in its own child first, but unsure how to target it that way.

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['FFR_NAME', $(".infobar").text()]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="infobar">
 <center><img src="" alt="image"></center>
 <span>Manufacturer</span>Apple<span>Part Number</span>
 <div class="productboxArticlenumber">MC723-US-4-500-REF</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ccs_cc_args = [];

var a = $('.infobar').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();

console.log(a)

ccs_cc_args.push(['FFR_NAME', a.trim()]);

console.log(ccs_cc_args)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infobar">
  <center>
    <img src="" alt="Apple">
  </center>
  <span>Manufacturer</span>thisistheAppletext<span>Part Number</span>
  <div class="productboxArticlenumber">MC723-US-4-500-REF</div>
</div>
```

1. Use node type == 3 meaning text.
2. Use [.contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

Comment: This works. Wrote it like this: `ccs_cc_args.push(['FFR_NAME', $('.infobar').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text()]);` only problem is that the output looks like this:  `["FFR_NAME", "\nApple\n\n"]] ` Not sure what the \n\n is?

Comment: why not use the variable?

Comment: Um - I was unsure how to write it in with .push part.. :p and couldnt make it work - it work they way i wrote it above.. except the /n part.

Comment: `ccs_cc_args.push(['FFR_NAME', a]);` try this way

Comment: Hmm.. Cant quite get it together - can you show an example?

Comment: use trim() to get white space updated the answer @JerrySvensson

Comment: happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [jQuery: Get the Text of Element without Child Element](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/).

For extra spacing, one can do as below:

```
$(".infobar").clone().children().remove().end().text().trim()
```

Watch the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/zgkv4ehd/).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ccs_cc_args = [];
  
  ccs_cc_args.push(['FFR_NAME', $(".infobar .infobarName").html()]);
  
  console.log(ccs_cc_args);
});
```

```css
.infobarName {
   font-weight: bold; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infobar">
   <center><img src="" alt="image"/></center>
   <span>Manufacturer</span> <span class="infobarName">Apple</span> <span>Part Number</span>
   <div class="productboxArticlenumber">MC723-US-4-500-REF</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm. Log shows as [["FFR_NAME", undefined]] - doesn't seems to fetch it correctly.

Comment: Weird, it seems to fetch it just fine at my side. Otherwise I wouldn't have inserted it into the post :/

Answer (score 0):

You can put your target word in span and do this

```js
window.onload = function () {

  'use strict';
  var chachedWord = [];

  // Select second span that exist in infobar ( 0 base index )
  var targetWord = document.querySelectorAll('.infobar span')[1];

  chachedWord.push('FFR_NAME' + ' ' + targetWord.textContent);

  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent = chachedWord;


};
```

```html
<div class="infobar">
  <center><img src="" alt="image"></center>
  <span>Manufacturer</span> <span>Apple</span> <span> Part Number</span>
  <div class="productboxArticlenumber">MC723-US-4-500-REF</div>
</div>
<p></p>
```

---

**JQuery**

```js
var chachedWord = [];

chachedWord.push('FFR_NAME' + ' ' + $('.infobar span').eq(1).text());

$('p').text(chachedWord);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infobar">
  <center><img src="" alt="image"></center>
  <span>Manufacturer</span> <span>Apple</span> <span> Part Number</span>
  <div class="productboxArticlenumber">MC723-US-4-500-REF</div>
</div>
<p></p>
```